# What are the practical applications of this trigonometric identity?

Tags: trigonometry

On various occasions people have asked here how to prove (but that is NOT the question here) that
$$
\text{if } \alpha+\beta+\gamma = \pi \text{ then } \frac{\sin(2\alpha) + \sin(2\beta) + \sin(2\gamma)} 2 = 2\sin\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma.
$$
I first saw this identity in 2006 when it got added to Wikipedia's [List of trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) by a logged-in user called Sriramoman, who alleged that it occurred perenially on the Joint Entrance Examination of the Indian Institutes of Technology.

It can be proved by methods that we all learned in secondary school, but I prefer a geometric proof that views the two equated quantities as different ways of expressing the area of a triangle inscribed in a circle of unit radius and in which the three angles are $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. (That is why I wrote it with factors of $1/2$ on the left and $2$ on the right rather than $1$ on the left and $4$ on the right.) (The fact that there is yet another reason to write it that way will wait for another occasion . . . )

**My question is** whether this identity has known applications, in physics, engineering, graphics, surveying, cartography, mathematics, or anything else?

Comment: Hm, if anything, it is a simple identity.

Comment: @SimpleArt : True, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something in your comment. $\qquad$

Comment: No, I just think its a simple/beautiful identity.

Comment: What if $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi n,n\in\mathbb Z?$

Comment: I think maybe $n\equiv1\bmod2$ might be what is needed. $\qquad$

Comment: Is it required that $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \leq \pi$ individually?

Comment: If there were an application where the product of three sines is required it would be arithmetically simpler to compute the result as a sum and division by four. In navigating the open ocean using spherical trigonometry navigators used trigonometric product to sum formulas to simplify navigation calculations. This also motivated the invention of logarithms.

Comment: @YuriyS $(\sin(2\alpha)+\sin(2\beta) + \sin(2(\pi -\alpha-\beta)))/2 - 2 \sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\sin(\pi-\alpha-\beta)$ is analytic in $\alpha, \beta$, so if it's true for $\alpha, \beta$ in some nonempty open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ it must be true for all $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb C^2$.

Comment: Its just  a common identity (not specific to the JEE of Indian Institutes of Technology). Actually they used to give it as a question in their subjective exams because it is in one of the questions in the assignments of the famous SL LONEY Plane Trigonometry Part 1book (written around (1860s). Apart from that, as far as I am concerned this identity has only been used to simplify maths expression by changing the addition of sines to their simple multiplication.

Comment: If Sidney Luxton Loney's book is famous outside of India, it's because biographical accounts of Ramanujan say he learned trigonometry from that book. $\qquad$